# How can i get viewed product also viewed other product list and also bought product list?

Tags: magento-1.9, best-seller, recently-viewed, buy-now

I am using magento ver 1.9.2.3 , how can i get viewed product also viewed product list and also bought product based on my customer list using available options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you wish to display a 'Recently Viewed Products' block?

You can do that using the following guide: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/recently-viewed-compared.html

[image]

[image]

To display past orders or bought products from past orders in your customer list you would have to use a module such as this: https://www.mageworx.com/products-ordered-by-customer-magento-extension.html

*1) PEOPLE WHO VIEWED THIS ALSO VIEWED*

Maybe this for starters: https://github.com/vovayatsyuk/magento-alsoviewed

*2) PEOPLE WHO BOUGHT THIS ALSO BOUGHT like Amazon.*

https://www.mageworx.com/others-also-bought-magento-extension.html

or https://github.com/georgeschiopu/alsobought

as examples.

Note: These modules linked are free. I am in no way connected to their creators.

Comment: Yes, you are right Recently Viewed Products is magento default one, i need to show 1) PEOPLE WHO VIEWED THIS ALSO VIEWED 2) PEOPLE WHO BOUGHT THIS ALSO BOUGHT like Amazon.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some links.